# Where was this photo taken? (Windows 10 lock screen)

Tags: where-on-earth, new-zealand, lock-screens

Can someone point to a location, where this photograph was taken?
It looks stunning!

This is one of lockscreen wallpapers in Windows 10.

[image]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Lake Quill, New Zealand.

source: [Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/where-was-the-photo-with-the-mountains-and-the/1fd66596-e5bb-43d9-af85-0d6943a13b1c?auth=1)

Comment: I love the MS representative's response: "It’s really unfortunate that you are facing this issue. But don't worry we will try to help you out." - Sounds like a canned response to me. That's funny.

Comment: @DavidB: What is perplexing is that “1 person found this helpful”.

Comment: I think one of the other photos is in NZ too, looks like Cathedral Cove.