# Where was this photograph used as a Windows 10 wallpaper taken?

Tags: where-on-earth, austria, lock-screens

The photograph below is available as a wallpaper in Windows 10. Where was it taken?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A right click on the image and Google says:

> Hallstatt, Village in Austria
>
> Hallstatt is a village in Austria's mountainous Salzkammergut region. Its 16th-century Alpine houses and Gothic Catholic church sit on Lake Hallstatt's western shore. A funicular connects to Salzwelten, an ancient salt mine with a subterranean salt lake and multimedia presentations on the village's mining history. To the west, a trail leads to the Echern Valley with its glacial potholes and Waldbachstrub Waterfall.

Comment: I find that win 10 will sometimes tell me itself where the picture came from, if I have an active network/wifi connection, just by clicking/tapping the little heart icon at the top of the screen...

Comment: @pnuts; I don't know that it does for all, and @Roddy of the Frozen Peas is correct; Win10 now seems to have embedded identification. An earlier answer here said that, but I haven't yet located it.

Comment: @pnuts: this may be the answer we remember, provided by JonathanReez http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74404/is-there-a-website-listing-the-location-of-all-the-windows-10-lock-screens

Comment: Right click on the Windows 10 lock screen? Right click on the photo in the question? Then choose which menu option?

Comment: @hippietrail: right click on the image, select 'Search Google for image,' et voila

Comment: @Dorothy: Ha! Must be a new feature in a recentish Chrome update I hadn't noticed before. Thanks!