# Location of photo used for Windows 10 desktop background?

Tags: where-on-earth, lock-screens, dolomites

This showed up as the background on my Windows 10 desktop:

[image: Windows 10 desktop background]

Does anyone know where the photo was taken?

Comment: Google says Sella Pass in the Val Gardena area of the Dolomites, a UNESCO World Heritage site.

Comment: Thanks Dorothy, you are exactly right. I found out the photo was taken by Matteo Zanvettor and he titled it "A New Day." Apparently you can get to where the photo was taken by riding up the Col-Raiser gondola at the Seceda ski area and hiking from there to the "Forcella Pana and the Odle Geisler."

Comment: Even though the name is embedded per the A by Michael C, I usually do a right click on the image and tell it to Google search (since I'm certainly not as techno savvy as so many here :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can find the description of the photo by going to "C:\Users\username_for_your_computer\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes" and then selecting the picture and going to its properties. It should contain information on where the photo was taken.

http://techdows.com/2016/01/where-windows-10-themes-photos-were-taken.html

Comment: +1, would you add an answer to the canonical also? This question is highly specific and your answer covers a lot of cases, so the canonical should have the same material also.

Comment: @GayotFow what do you mean by canonical? I don't understand it in the context you are using it in.

Comment: A canonical question is meant to cover all different variations on an often asked question. The one meant here is http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74404/is-there-a-website-listing-the-location-of-all-the-windows-10-lock-screens

Comment: @MichaelC. what Willeke said, please add your answer there as well as here. It's a more generic question, thanks.

Comment: This answer did not work for me. Using file Explorer in Windows 10 I went to C:\Users, but at that location my only options were folders named "default.migrated," "DefaultAppPool," "Owner," and "Public." I couldn't find anything related to "username_for_your_computer."

Comment: @Joe It could be under owner.