# Where is this place "several houses on the rocky coast and rocky island with natural arch"?

Tags: where-on-earth, lock-screens

Where is this place "several houses on the rocky coast and rocky island with natural arch"?

[image]

If you think that I can check location on windows lock screen ([Is there a website listing the location of all the Windows 10 lock screens?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74404/is-there-a-website-listing-the-location-of-all-the-windows-10-lock-screens)) look at this and tell me how:

[image]

Comment: @pnuts, I like the place so I'd like to no where it is. And go there one day

Comment: @Dorothy, what about my explanation?

Comment: @Dorothy, this is NOT working in my localized version of Windows

Comment: @pnuts, , this is NOT working in my localized version of Windows

Comment: Try a right click on the image and selecting Google search

Comment: Could you tell me what country you are in? Google Image Translate can't detect that language for me

Comment: So Google thinks this is russian. The dialog box message (not the title) says **Thanks for the tip! He will help us improve this function in the (near) future.** I have no idea why Google Translate got that but thats what it got.

Comment: OP, could you try following the following guide? http://superuser.com/a/1112013/300801 - it should show you the texts later

Comment: I am suggesting to reopen (but not enough rep to vote) because the linked question asks about a *website* whereas this question asks about a *location*, therefore **not** a duplicate.

Comment: @JoshM, you are right about translation. The idea is "this feature is not working yet"

Answer (score 4):

It is in **Sennen, United Kingdom**.

A reverse Google Image Search returned "Lands End". Visually Similar Images brought me to this link:

http://www.intocornwall.com/engine/azabout.asp?guide=Land%27s+End

So, Google search "lands end cornwall" and it will bring up multiple links of interest.

Hope this helps!