# What is the location of photo used for Windows 10 lock screen?

Tags: international-travel, identify-this

[image]

Where is this image from? Any help would be great!

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74404/is-there-a-website-listing-the-location-of-all-the-windows-10-lock-screens

Answer (score 6):

Ollantaytambo, Peru

Third picture in the gallery - https://www.calazan.com/gallery/70/