# Where is this win10 wallpaper location?

Tags: nature-and-wildlife

[image]

Does anyone know this location? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

As JonathanReez told us in his [anwser on travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/77875/66089) you can click the "like what you see?" button or the small globe to find out.

Comment: Assuming that the "like what you see?" button is actually there.  It's hit or miss on my  Win10 system that I get a choice and there are numerous threads online of people asking how to get the control to show.

Comment: @PeterM: The "like what you see" button will always show up if there's no prompt asking you to input your username/password. Sadly, I haven't yet found a way to cancel this prompt to get the button back... only workaround would be to log in and pressing WIN+L again to bring the screen back.

Comment: @waka Your experience differs from mine.  I have male experience of no buttons being visible.  And so have a bunch of other people.

Comment: @PeterM Please follow the steps here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/windows-spotlight-like-what-you-see-option-is/655095b6-8492-45ba-aaa6-f9c2b947f115

Comment: @DaanvanHoek Been there, done that, got the T-shirt and still no button.

Comment: @PeterM Windows can be horrible to treat, when broken. Maybe try to ask on superuser or try this: https://superuser.com/questions/1272949/how-can-i-display-like-what-you-see-at-windows-login

Comment: @DaanvanHoek That's not I haven't tried, but solving this issue is not high on my list.  Sometimes I actually *do* see the button, but most times I don't.