# Which city can be seen on this Windows 10 lockscreen?

Tags: identify-this, rivers

I had this as my Windows lockscreen, tried to google it, but I couldn't find it. Does anyone know what city this is?[image]

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but there is a built-in way to find out where the lock screen pictures are. If you move your mouse while on the lock screen, a couple of new text items will appear - one in the top left, and one in the middle of the screen. Click the one in the middle, unlock your computer, and it will open a new browser tab taking you to a Bing page with information about the motive.
You can also hover over the Like What You See text in the top right and see a general location of the photo. See also this question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74404/is-there-

Comment: @PhilippNagel I wish this were always available. Sadly, on many occasions (maybe 10-20% of lockscreens I see), hovering does not show that text, and once or twice the text in the same position was replaced with some babble about how to use Windows more efficiently.

Comment: @PhilippNagel This is (sadly) not always available. I believe this can be block by some kind of corporate policy. Don't know why they would do it, but I have a computer from a customer that is like that.

Comment: Yeah, normally it should be there, but I tried that and it didn't show up, I don't know why. Usually it's a something like "Do you like what you see?" but even after refreshing it, it still wasn't there.  Thank you for your comment anyways!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This appears to be **Rome**.  The smaller stadium closer to the viewer is the [Stadio del Tennis di Roma](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stadio_del_tennis_di_Roma) (Rome Tennis Stadium);  the larger stadium behind it is the [Stadio Olimpico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stadio_Olimpico) (Olympic Stadium).  The large blocky building in the distance the Ministry of Foreign Affairs.  The steel arch bridge in the foreground is the Ponte della Musica (Music Bridge), which crosses the Tiber River.  As this bridge was built in 2008–2011, the picture must have been taken within the last 10 years or so.

[Google Earth view (in browser).](https://www.google.com/maps/place/41%C2%B055'52.3%22N+12%C2%B027'23.4%22E/@41.9127298,12.4598265,537a,35y,350.68h,76.2t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d41.9312!4d12.4565?hl=en)

Comment: Rome is extremely green, @gerrit

Answer (score 14):

I right clicked on the image in Google Chrome, selected "Search Google for this image", which led me to a search page which led me [here](http://shutterstock.puzzlepix.hu/kereses?query=pietrangeli), which led me [here](http://shutterstock.puzzlepix.hu/kep/1233199366). Caption: Aerial drone bird's eye view photo of iconic sports complex of Foro Italico featuring famous Obelisk of Mussolini, Rome, Italy