# Where is there this large rock in the French Riviera?

Tags: where-on-earth, landmarks, french-riviera

This came up on my lock screen but it didn't contain any specific location details. I'm trying to find where this is located. All I know is that this photo was taken in the French Riviera (Côte d'Azur). Anyone might have an idea where this huge rock next to a town is?

[image: High rock stands over french village connected by stone bridge over river]

Comment: Related: [This](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/77875/73830) and [this](https://superuser.com/q/1011968/632320).

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sisteron_-_Rocher_de_la_Baume.jpg

Answer (score 10):

That's [Rocher de la Baume](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g196686-d10713180-Reviews-Rocher_de_la_Baume-Sisteron_Alpes_de_Haute_Provence_Provence_Alpes_Cote_d_Azur.html) in Sisteron.

Comment: About 100 miles from the Côte d'Azur...

Comment: Yes. Sisteron is in the Alpes-de-Haute-Provence, a long way from the coast (Côte).