# Where was this picture taken?

Tags: germany, lock-screens

[image]

Can someone help find out what is the location of this picture? I tried enabling the ''Tips'' option for the Windows lock screen but it still does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a website listing the location of all the Windows 10 lock screens?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74404/is-there-a-website-listing-the-location-of-all-the-windows-10-lock-screens)

Comment: My first thought was river Rhine in Germany. Somewhere near: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankt_Goarshausen#/media/Datei:Panorama_Sankt_Goarshausen.jpg

Comment: It could be here -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moselle

Comment: A google reverse image search tells us it's in Germany, not Switzerland: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beilstein,_Rhineland-Palatinate#/media/File:BeilsteinMoselPanorama1.jpg

Comment: So it's Germany actually. Thank you very much all for your answers! It really helps.

Answer (score 19):

Hint: the first thing to do in such a situation is a reverse image search on Google. Pasting the URL of the image directly yields [Belstein, in Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beilstein,_Rhineland-Palatinate), not Switzerland.

[image]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beilstein,_Rhineland-Palatinate#/media/File:BeilsteinMoselPanorama1.jpg)