# What's the name of this fjords scenery?

Tags: identify-this, lock-screens

I found this fjords scenery during the login screen of Windows 10:

[image]

What's the name of this fjords scenery ?

Comment: Not a duplicate as I do not know whether it still works https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74404/is-there-a-website-listing-the-location-of-all-the-windows-10-lock-screens for most pictures Windows gives they do give the name and location of you click on the right part of the screen.

Comment: Have you tried an online search for the picture?

Comment: @Willeke I am tried clicking on locking screen all over to get location name may be I am using different version/

Comment: @Willeke While that is a great way to find the location (and I've done it so many times for some great photos), it requires the link "Like what you see?" (or similar wording) on the screen at top-right, and for some reason Windows doesn't always show it.  You can see it's not present in this screenshot, so unfortunately not an option here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google Images finds the picture to be of:

- **The Reinebringen hike in the Lofoten Islands, Norway.**

The website [How to hike Reinebringen](https://www.earthtrekkers.com/how-to-hike-reinebringen-in-the-lofoten-islands-norway/) shows not exact but similar pictures, such as this:

[image]

<sub>*Copyright © 2023 Earth Trekkers*</sub>

Comment: I suppose this photo was taken from the peak in the centre-right foreground of the OP's posted photo.

Comment: I don't think so. To me it is pretty clear that OPs photo was only taken a few meters behind the POV of your photo. Maybe also a little bit lower to the ground, so the lake to the left and the city are a bit more obscured.

Comment: @Opifex I think there’s more than a few metres between them: look at the angle of the town to the peninsula with a cliff-face behind it, in both photos. OP’s photo seems to have been taken from far to the left of @WeatherVane’s

Comment: @CharlieHarding indeed, the Earth Trekkers' photo looks along the left arm of the body of water, but on the log/lock screen that stretch of water is mostly behind a ridge. Many of the pictures on Google Images show someone standing on that little pinnacle of rock, so I guess it's a favourite vantage point.