# Which city is shown on this Windows lock screen wallpaper?

Tags: identify-this

Can you please tell me, which city is shown on this Windows lock screen wallpaper (suggestion Netherlands, but not Amsterdam, or Dutch part of Belgium, probably Bruges?)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What have you tried so far in order to identify the city?

Comment: Well, I done the pic and upload it here. Thanks!

Comment: If that's a Windows login screen then there should be a camera icon at the top right that tells you all the location details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a website listing the location of all the Windows 10 lock screens?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74404/is-there-a-website-listing-the-location-of-all-the-windows-10-lock-screens)

Comment: There are hotspots that show up on the lock screen with a magnifying glass icon that share factoids about the picture. Click on them and they will tell you more about the actual location.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I’m not sure why you think this isn’t Amsterdam.

Google Images tells us it’s Sint Olofssteeg in Amsterdam, and Google Maps confirms it. The photo was taken from next to 17 Oudezids Voorburgwal

https://maps.app.goo.gl/GvuQofFwXcNoinqH8

Comment: Thank you very much. Was my mistake

Comment: Houses in Amsterdam usually do not stand in the water but this part of town is the exception. So I can understand people not expecting it to be Amsterdam.

Comment: Almost correct, but wrong addresses. The photo was taken from the Oudezijds Voorburgwal (spelling!) standing next to Sint Odolfssteeg 15 (or thereabout), and shows the Oudezijds Achterburgwal (left) Voorburgwal (right), and the house called 'Vredenburg' in the middle.

Comment: (The photo itself does not show the Sint Odolfssteeg, regardless of what Google may say. [See OpenStreetMap for the layout](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=19/52.37546/4.90026&layers=P).)